# A classical jQuery error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I have some JS functions in my page, and I got this error. I removed everything but the incriminated lines and I still get this error.

I searched this forum and the web, so I tried to add : semicolons, (jQuery), add the $ to the function arguments... I still get the same error.

I use jQuery 1.11.2, declared in my header.

Here is the whole code for those who asked :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >
<head>  
<script type= "text/javascript" src= "jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>Exporter les données d'une base<BR><BR></h2>
<HR></HR>
<form method="post" action="execute_function.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
include 'functions.php';
propose_choix_BDD();
?>
<BR>
<div class="camp">
</div>
<div class="fichier">
</div>
<BR><BR><BR>

<div class="button">
<?php
submit_button("Export_KML");
submit_button("Export_csv");
?>  
</div>
<input type= "hidden" name="export_campagne" value="true" />
</form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("I start");
    $(function(){
        $('.camp').on('change',"#id_camp_ch",function()  { //error here
            alert ("I change !");
            }); 
    console.log("I stop");
    }); 

    </script>
</body>
<?php
retour_index();
?>
```

`propose_choix_BDD()` echoes a dropdown with DB inside, `div class="camp"` contains some tables echoed when a jQuery change is detected in the DB menu (script removed for clarity reasons). So `.camp` is dynamically filled. Once it is, I'd like my JS to detect a change made by the user in the dropdown menu. `#id_camp_ch` is the name of the id of the `<select>` that wraps this menu.

I agree that as I have cut a part of my code, `.camp` will remain empty. In other words, `#id_campagne_choix` will never exist. But it won't exist in the beginning too even if I use my full script. So I shouldn't get such an error ...

I also tried to put all my script at the bottom of the document.

If I remove the lines `$( ".camp" )...})` the alert does display.

If you have any idea for this it'll be awesome :)

Comment: where you use this onload() function? can you add HTML code here ?

Comment: It will not fix your problem, but start by replacing `onload = function() {` by `$(function(){` and don't forget close brakets `});`

Comment: ok message edited : the code is at the very beginning of my body. Ok thanks I'll replace it

Comment: If I replace onload = function () by what you suggested, I got one more error. But the error messages are also a bit more accurate.

 `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionexport.php:29 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.js:438 jQuery.extend.readyjquery-1.11.2.js:868 DOMContentLoaded
export.php:29 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionexport.php:29 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.js:438 jQuery.extend.ready`

Comment: need some `html` to be more concrete!

Comment: done ! see the original post

Answer (score 0):

Their is a error, Please try the following code...

```
onload = function() {

            $( ".camp" ).on("change","#id_camp_ch",function()  {
                alert ("change !");
                });             
        };
```

But rather you should use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".camp" ).on("change","#id_camp_ch",function()  {
                    alert ("change !");
                    }); 
});
```

The `onchange` will fire when DOM is ready.

Comment: thanks but the onchange will never fire in my case because I removed the lines that fill my DIV with a dropdown menu. The DIV exists, but it's empty. But the fact it won't fire doesn't mean that I must have this error ;)

I tried your code but my error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the purpose of changing a div, because divs don't have the change listener.

You could use one of this examples to help:

```
<form method="post" action="execute_function.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<BR>
change me!
<input type="text" class="camp"><br>
or me
<input type="text" id="id_camp_ch"><br>
dont change me! i won't make anything!
<input type="text" id="id_camp_ch" class="camp">
</id>
<div class="fichier">
And never change ME!!!!!
<select id="test">
<option></option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</div>
<BR><BR><BR>

<div class="button">
</div>
<input type= "hidden" name="export_campagne" value="true" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#id_camp_ch.camp').change(function()  {
alert ("I said to u dont change me!!!"); //or do what u need
});
</script>
```

I think also that the div tag don't have the change listener, that's why it's throwing the error.

If the `id_camp_ch` is a children of the div with style camp, or something else then you should use .`camp>#id_camp_ch` instead of `.camp#id_camp_ch`.

I think you can solve it by using the right selectors instead of using the `.on()` function.

Comment: thanks for your help ! Actually, I thought I had to specify #id_camp_ch because it is the id of the dynamically-generated dropdown menu, and because I wanna handle it.
I read the documentation and the forums, and I understood that for handling a dynamically-generated element, it was not possible to use the .change event. Instead they recommend to use an existing tag (like div class="camp") then a zone in this tag (#id_camp_ch) with the event 'change'. The div tag does not have the change listener I agree, but the select does. Could my problem come from this ?

Comment: .camp#id_camp_ch does not send an error anymore ! thanks ! but my event is still uncaught...i'll investigate into this direction !

Comment: And to answer fully your question, I also use the DIV .camp in order to append here the results resulting from my first jQuery call.

Comment: If answeredr please mark this post a closed or post the answer to your own question case u got it!

Answer (score 0):

I finally downloaded once again jQuery v2.1.1. and it worked ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Include [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) before using it.

Enjoy :)

Comment: _I use jQuery 1.11.2, declared in my header._

Comment: Its part of question which OP has asked, If you want code then ask OP not me.